# How can I jq a line from a file from a remote server?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, jq

I would like to check a particular line from a remote server. So far, I can check if the file exists or not. But can I index a particular line using tool like jq?

```
if ssh -q -i $pathToPem $sshUsernameIp [ -f ${remote_serial} ];

        then

            echo "Serial number is found externally"
            serialNumber=$(cat serialNumber.json | jq '.serialNumber')

            if ssh -q -i $pathToPem $sshUsernameIp [ "$serialNumber" == "${remote_serial | jq '.serialNumber'}" ];
                then
                    echo "Serial number is same"
                else
                    echo "Serial number is not same"
            fi
fi
```

output>

```
Serial number is found externally
./test.sh: line 127: ${remote_serial | jq '.serialNumber'}: bad substitution
```

How can I pass variable inside {} there? Can I compare these local and remote files without scp ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make it complicated.  Just grab the JSON off from the remote host and pass it through `jq`, then do the same locally. Then compare.  If the remote file is missing, you'll get an error (which we can throw away), and the serial numbers will compare different (unless the local serial number is also missing).

```
r_serial=$( ssh -q -i "$pathToPem" "$sshUsernameIp" cat "$remote_serial" 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.serialNumber' )
l_serial=$( jq -r '.serialNumber' serialNumber.json )

if [ "$r_serial" = "$l_serial" ]; then
    echo 'same'
else
    echo 'different (or missing)'
fi
```

This is assuming that `$remote_serial` is the pathname of the JSON document on the remote machine.

Note also the quoting of the variable expansions in the call to `ssh`.

---

The actual error you get comes from the fact that

```
"${remote_serial | jq '.serialNumber'}"
```

is not a valid variable expansion.  You may have wanted to use something like

```
"$( printf '%s\n' "$remote_serial" | jq '.serialNumber' )"
```

but that assumes that `$remote_serial` contains the contents of a JSON document.

Comment: Thank you. This one makes it look clean as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be

```
"$(echo ${remote_serial} | jq '.serialNumber')"
```

instead of

```
"${remote_serial | jq '.serialNumber'}"
```

Comment: I tried it, seems like I will have difficulty with parsing with this.
```parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
bash: line 0: [: sfsdfsdfdfsdfsd: unary operator expected
Serial number is not same```

Comment: I see Kusalananda already supplied you with a better solution with proper quoting. My assumption that the `${remote_serial}` might not have spaces nor any other problematic characters was probably incorrect. Kusalananda's solution has properly defensive quoting to handle that.